# What is the name for inline/text/json with regard to Mojolicious handlers?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

What is the name of the thing on the side of the fat-arrow in

```
$c->render(inline => 'The result is <%= 1 + 1 %>.');
$c->render(text => 'I ♥ Mojolicious!');
$c->render(json => {foo => [1, 'test', 3]});
```

And how can I write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments to `render` just set stash values internally. That's why they don't have a name. It seems these are special stash values that [Mojolicious::Renderer](https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/11d926f4a92a76f29f766a7d5605034b5d00b97c/lib/Mojolicious/Renderer.pm#L78) uses.

If you want to creaet a special thing that render special stuff, the way is with a handler,

https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Adding-your-favorite-template-system

Comment: "The arguments to render just set stash values internally." You can show this in that `$c->render(data => $bytes);` is exactly the same as `$c->stash(data => $bytes); $c->render;` (and in fact you don't even need to call `render` manually in most cases).